# How does Compiz decide which windows should be sticky?

Tags: linux, window-manager, compiz

How does Compiz automatically decide which windows should be sticky (i.e. should be visible on all workspaces)? Windows such as gnome-panel and cairo-dock always stay on the visible workspace, without requiring additional configuration. How does Compiz figure this out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program sets [hints](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#id2551694) on the window that the window manager examines to determine behavior.

Comment: Does Windows have window hints like these? Does it have a means of making windows sticky (i.e. unmoveable)?

Comment: Windows hasn't really supported multiple workspaces, so something like "sticky" would be defined in whatever tool you're using for that. Most of them maintain an internal list of which window belongs in which space, so they'd store that info there as well.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that things like hints exist in order to allow the WM to be replaced by something else. Since this isn't feasible in Windows, there doesn't need to be any such equivalent.